# Parallelogram and cosine rule

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, quadrilateral

The parallelogram $ABCD$ is determined by $AB=8,AD=10$ and $\measuredangle BAD=60^\circ$. The perpendicular bisector $s_{BD}$ of $BD$ intersects $AD$ and $BC$ at $K$ and $M$, respectively. Find $BK$ and $KM$.

> $BK=7,KM=4\sqrt7$

[image]
First, I am trying to find $BK$. The cosine rule on triangle $ABK$ gives $$BK^2={AK}^2+AB^2-2.AK.AB.\cos60^\circ.$$ We don't know only the length of $AK$. How can I find it?

Comment: $AK=10-BK$  because $BKD$ is iscoseles triangle

Comment: Why the downvote? I added a diagram, wrote my thoughts on the problem. I think that this community really have too high expectations. Have a nice day!

Comment: @MAGNUM, thank you! I solved it and got that $BK=7$. Can you give me a hint on finding $KM$?

Comment: $KM=2KO,    KO^2= BK^2-BO^2$

Comment: $KO = OM, DO = OB$ and $KM\perp BD$. We know the length of $KD = 7$ and the length of $BD$ by cosine theorem.

Comment: @MAGNUM if I had seen your comment before answering, it would have saved me sometime :)

Comment: @player3236 , how do we know that $O$ is the midpoint of $KM$. We don't?

Comment: We do; $\triangle AKO \cong \triangle CMO$ via ASA.

Comment: We know because take $\angle ADB = \theta$ then what is $\angle KBO$? And what is $\angle MBO$?

Comment: @player3236, we have $AO=CO$ and $\angle AOK=\angle COM$. What more?

Comment: $\angle OAK = \angle OCM$. We are working with a parallelogram here.

Comment: @player3236, these angles are not external angles, are they? Why are they equal?

Comment: They are alternate angles with respect to $AD // BC$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Magnum's comment.
As you pointed out $$BK^2=AK^2+AB^2-2\cdot AK\cdot AB\cdot\cos\measuredangle BAK$$ Note that $BK=DK$ so let $BK=DK=x$. Then $AK=10-x$. Plugging in gives $$x^2=(10-x)^2+64-2\cdot8\cdot(10-x)\cdot\dfrac12\Rightarrow x=7$$